# Authenticating two endpoints with one request

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I need to access a REST API which takes bearer token for authentication, and is behind a gateway which has basic 'user id and password' authentication.

I am trying by adding first an authorization header explicitly and then passing bearer token as regular header.

```
                byte[] cred = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_gatewayUserID + ":" + _gatewayPassword);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(cred));
                var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage
                {
                    Method = HttpMethod.Post,
                    RequestUri = new Uri("https://APIURL.com/api"),
                    Headers = {
                        { HttpRequestHeader.Authorization.ToString(), "Bearer " + _bearerToken },
                        { HttpRequestHeader.Accept.ToString(), "application/json" }
                    },
                    Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj))
                };

                var response = client.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage).Result;
```

I am getting unauthorized access message. This is coming from gateway because I am able to directly access REST API successfully with bearer token.

I checked the request string and it seems the request is ignoring the basic authentication and just keeping the bearer token and therefore failing to authenticate gateway endpoint.

Please let me know how can I make this request.

Comment: You're setting the HTTP `Authorization` header **twice** (first with ``client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization`, then a second time with `Headers = { HttpRequestHeader.Authorization... `). You need to choose which one you want to use in the request.

Comment: `Convert.ToBase64String(cred)` <-- You have numerous bugs in your code that generates `cred`, for example, RFC 7617 says to use ISO-8859-1 encoding _and not_ UTF-8 for the `Basic` auth header: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7617#appendix-B.3

Comment: @Dai , I am using Authorization twice because first I need request to pass through basic authentication gateway endpoint and then it need to authenticate API endpoint that accepts bearer token. This is my main concern, I need to know how I can send request to authenticate two endpoints.

Comment: You can't have 2 authentications for an endpoint. Either use basic or bearer auth. If it's someone elses API ask them for an example how to call the endpoint, cause it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @LLL , there are two endpoints in play here, mapped with each other. Main API endpoint belongs to a third party and they have bearer authentication for their APIs, our company doesn't allow direct external API access and therefore they map the third party API behind a gateway endpoint and provide us their mapped endpoint URL with basic authentication credentials. If I send only basic credentials then it fails to authenticate third party API.

Comment: Sounds like the gateway endpoint is a proxy for the 3rd party endpoint? Is the API GW managed by your company? if so ask them how are you supposed to authenticate both their proxy and the target endpoint, because you can't do both in a single request unless they provide a different header where you can put the basic auth (user name + pw). But if you put the basic auth in `Authorization` header then the bearer won't work, and if you put the bearer, then it will overwrite the basic auth and it won't work either.

Comment: You could try using `Proxy-Authorization`, perhaps the API GW supports it? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Proxy-Authenticate